# Pull-back metric

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to compute the components of a pull-back metric. Is that correct or am I missing something?

Let $M$ and $N$ be smooth manifolds of dimension m and n respectively. Let $\Phi:M\rightarrow N$ be a smooth map. Suppose that $N$ is endowed with a metric $\tilde{g}$ such that ($N,\tilde{g}$) is a Riemannian manifold. We would like to pull-back the metric $\tilde{g}$ through $\Phi$ in order to make ($M,g$) a Riemannian manifold, where $g:=\Phi^*\tilde{g}$.

Let's examine how the 2-covariant tensor $g\in\Gamma((T^*M)^{\otimes 2})$ works on $\Gamma(TM)\otimes\Gamma(TM)$. Let $V,W\in\Gamma(TM)$ be vector fields on M, then $g(V,W)\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ is just a smooth function on M, defined conventionally as
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{crcl}
g(V,W):&M&\rightarrow &\mathbb{R}\\
&p &\mapsto &g_p(V_p,W_p). 
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
So by defintition of $g$ we have
\begin{equation*}
g(V,W)=\Phi^*\tilde{g}(V,W)=\tilde{g}(\Phi_*(V),\Phi_*(W)),
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{cccl}
\Phi_*:&\Gamma(TM)&\rightarrow&\Gamma(TN)\\
&V &\mapsto &\Phi_*(V)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
is the push forward of $\Phi$, defined by $(\Phi_*(V))_{\Phi(p)}:=d\Phi_p(V_p)$ and $d\Phi_p$ is the differential of $\Phi$ at $p\in M$ that acts on tangent spaces as follows:
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{array}{cccl}
d\Phi_p:&T_pM&\rightarrow&T_{\Phi(p)}N\\
&v &\mapsto &d\Phi_p(v)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
producing a derivation $d\Phi_p(v)$ in $T_{\Phi(p)}N$ that is defined by
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{array}{cccl}
d\Phi_p(v):&\mathcal{C}^\infty(N)&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\
&g &\mapsto &d\Phi_p(v)(g):=v(g\circ\Phi).
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
We can also define the vector field $\Phi_*(V)$ in this equivalent formulation:
\begin{equation*}
 \begin{array}{cccl}
\Phi_*(V):&\mathcal{C}^\infty(N)&\rightarrow&\mathcal{C}^\infty(N)\\
&g &\mapsto &\Phi_*(V)(g)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
defined by $(\Phi_*(V)(g))(\Phi(p)):=d\Phi_p(V_p)(g)=V_p(g\circ\Phi)\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let's now work in coordinates: let $x^1,...,x^n$ be coordinates on N and $y^1,...,y^m$ coordinates on M, then $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}\}_{i=1}^n$ is a local frame for $\Gamma(TN)$ and $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^j}}\}_{j=1}^m$ is a local frame for $\Gamma(TM)$. Then, by definition, since $V,W\in\Gamma(TM)$, we can infer that there exist smooth functions $\{V^s\}_{s=1}^m,\{W^p\}_{p=1}^m\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ such that locally we can write $V=V^s\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^s}}$ and $W=W^p\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^p}}$.

In the same way, since $\Phi_*(V),\Phi_*(W)\in\Gamma(TN)$ there exist functions $\{A^q\}_{q=1}^n,\{B^r\}_{r=1}^n\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(N)$ such that locally we can write $\Phi_*(V)=A^q\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^q}}$ and $\Phi_*(W)=B^r\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^r}}$.

Then we get, using this notation, that
\begin{equation*}
g(V,W)=g\left(V^s\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^s}},W^p\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^p}}\right)=V^sW^pg\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^s}},\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^p}}\right)=:V^sW^pg_{sp}.
\end{equation*}
On the other hand we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
g(V,W)&=\Phi^*\tilde{g}(V,W)=\tilde{g}(\Phi_*(V),\Phi_*(W))\tilde{g}\left(A^q\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^q}},B^r\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^r}}\right)\\
&=A^qB^r\tilde{g}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^q}},\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^r}}\right)=:A^qB^r\tilde{g}_{qr}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Then it holds that
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
V^sW^pg_{sp}=A^qB^r\tilde{g}_{qr}.
\end{equation}
Now consider $V:=\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^s}}$ and $W:=\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^p}}$, so that $g(V,W)=g_{sp}$. We have to find the functions $\{A^q\}_{q=1}^n,\{B^r\}_{r=1}^n\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(N)$. Since, by definition $\Phi_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^s}})=A^q\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^q}}$ this must be true for all smooth functions $g\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(N)$, i.e. $\Phi_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^s}})(g)=A^q\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^q}}(g)$. Apply this to the special case $g:=x^k$ and we get
\begin{equation*}
\Phi_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^s}}\right)(x^k)=\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^s}}(x^k\circ\Phi)=\frac{\partial{\Phi^k}}{\partial{y^s}},
\end{equation*}
where we have defined $\Phi^k:=x^k\circ \Phi$ and on the other hand
\begin{equation*}
A^q\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^q}}(x^k)=A^q\delta^k_q=A^k.
\end{equation*}
So we have found that $A^q=\frac{\partial{\Phi^q}}{\partial{y^s}}$ and so $\Phi_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^s}}\right)=\frac{\partial{\Phi^q}}{\partial{y^s}}\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^q}}$. In the same way we get $B^r=\frac{\partial{\Phi^r}}{\partial{y^p}}$ and $\Phi_*\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial{y^p}}\right)=\frac{\partial{\Phi^r}}{\partial{y^p}}\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^r}}$.
Then recalling $g_{sp}=A^qB^r\tilde{g}_{qr}$ we get
\begin{equation*}
g_{sp}=\frac{\partial{\Phi^q}}{\partial{y^s}}\frac{\partial{\Phi^r}}{\partial{y^p}}\tilde{g}_{qr}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: I use the fact that $\Phi$ is injective and surjective where I compute the push forward. Is it necessary?

Comment: Your calculations are correct. You need that $d\Phi$ be injective in order that $g$ is a metric. Injectivity and surjectivity of $\Phi$ is not important.